# How convert number_formated output to numbers?

Tags: php

i want to convert number_formated output like 129,888.0 to 1298880 to return function when edit from db.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Simply convert 129,888.0 to 1298880?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$string` is the number_formatted output, then this will turn it back to a number by removing any non-numeric characters.

```
$number = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', null, $string);
```

As an aside, you should really store things *un*-formatted and just format them when you want to display them.

Comment: If you only want to remove the comma, then you don't need `preg_replace`, you can use `str_replace(',', null, $string)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $numstr = "100,000,000.75";
 $num = doubleval(str_replace(",",".",$mynumstr));
```